# "This method must return a result of type ModelAndView." - when returning a result of type ModelAndView

Tags: java, httpserver, modelandview

In the `LoginView` method it shows an error that there must be a return of type `ModelAndView`. But I am returning a result of type `ModelAndView`.

```
@RequestMapping("/login")
public  loginView( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse res)
{
    String name = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");

    if(password.equals("admin")){
        return new ModelAndView("hipage","","");                
    }
}
```

Comment: As it is that code is uncompilable, is it your actual code? There are at least 2 things missing: the declaration of the return type as well as what should be returned is the password isn't "admin" (btw please never use that in any production system).

Comment: Where's the return type?

Comment: "return new modelAndView"

Comment: There is a return missing when the IF condition is not true. Also, as  @Steve-Smith noted, the return type (in the method structure, beginning with "public") is missing. This shouldn't compile as far as I know. It should begin like "public ModelAndView loginView(...".

Comment: @dr0i  Thank you both of you.i got it now and it's work fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I already have one how I fix this

Only having a `return statement` doesn't make your method to return something you should specify which type of data your method is going to return (if you want to return something) else `void`

So Correct method implementation is below:

```
@RequestMapping("/login")
public ModelAndView loginView( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse res)
{
  // Your code logic with the proper return statement.
}
```

**Note:** Once you add the return statement in method declaration you also have to return something from the `else` block to handle the case when password doesn't meet your expected result.

Comment: whosoever downvoted, do comment so that I can improve the answer or can remove it. if the answer is not appropriate. But do care to comment

Answer (score 0):

Your return statement is in a if.

try to add a return type after you public [...] methodName

and a return out of you if case.

```
public Object method(boolean test) { 
    if (!test) {
        return test;
    } 
    return null;
}
```